# How to enable buttons that were disabled via asynchrous trigger via code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, postback

I have a couple of buttons in an update panel that gets disabled from code behind on certain triggers like depending it wrote to database or not. Now on the client i have a reset button, This button resets all components on the page like a asp:dropdown, textbox etc, except for the ones in the update panel. I'm usning a javascript to reset it but these ones in the update panel never gets reset. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<td valign="top" align="center"  width="50%">

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updTxtGen" runat="server"     UpdateMode="Conditional"> 
        <ContentTemplate> 
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtGenVVOE" name= "txtGenVVOE"  TextMode="MultiLine" 
                runat="server"  style="font-size: 11px" rows="4" cols="44" Width="324px>
            </asp:TextBox>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCreateNote" EventName="Click" />     
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

</td></tr>
<tr>  <td valign="top" align="center" width="50%"> 
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateCopy" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate> 
            <asp:Button  name ="btnCopy" ID="btnCopy" class="btn"  runat="server"
                onmouseover="this.className='btn btnhov'"
                onmouseout="this.className='btn'" style="background: silvergradient" 
                Text="COPY" OnClientClick="ClipBoard();return false;" 
                ToolTip="Copy Text to ClipBoard"  /> 
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCreateNote" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and my JS script is very simple , i get the

```
 document.getElementById('btnCopy').enabled = true;
 document.getElementById('txtGenVVOE').enabled = true;
```

Like I mentioned , all elements get reset except the ones disabled from code behind.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search suggests this might be the answer:

```
document.getElementById('btnCopy').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('txtGenVVOE').diabled = false;
```

Comment: As a side note I have always used .disabled when disabling buttons so it is not purely a blind google suggestion either.

Comment: Please mark as answer so that people will see its been answered.